# How can I make a Trusted Publishers certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, revit-api

He is creating a plugin for the Revit program. Every time Revit is opened, it detects this plugin and gives "Security Unsigned Plugin" error. Even though I marked it as "Always-Load" to accept this error, it keeps giving the same error. For this, I had to create a digital certificate. I saw that I could do it with Makecert.exe, but when I searched on stackowerflow and google, I couldn't find it in a clear way. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Konrad Sobon recently explained step by step how to [create a self-signed code signing certificate for yourself](https://archi-lab.net/creating-a-self-signed-code-signing-certificate), cf. The Building Coder post on how to [Roll Your Own Verified Publisher](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2022/06/parameters-snippets-batch-mode-and-self-signing.html#3).